# Show textview on top of GridView for every n Imageviews like Gallery timeline

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview

I am trying to build a layout as shown in the image where the Date(TextView) is shown above the images in GridView and the TextView appears multiple times in view .I am confused on how to implement it. I tried putting TextView in list item but in that case TextView is repeating for each row. Can anyone suggest how to go with this.Reference image attached.

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/lvTimeline"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rlText">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="28 Feb"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gvTest"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dp">

</GridView>
```

gridview_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="116dp"
    android:layout_height="116dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/ivTimeline"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>
```

List adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        holder.gvTimeline = (GridView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.gvTest);


        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.gvTimeline.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(imagesList));


    return view;

}



public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvDate;
    GridView gvTimeline;
}
```

GridView Adapter :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivTimeline);
         view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.ivImage.setImageResource(getItem(position));


    return view;

}



public static class ViewHolder {
   ImageView ivImage;
}
```

[image]

Image which I am getting now :
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the java code for this?

Comment: @Arlind Added Java code. Please check.

Comment: It looks good whats the problem with it ?

Comment: In the image attached, there is a date and then some images. In my case, I get TextView for every row. How can I make it possible just like image.

Comment: maybe thats just how many GridView items you have per ListView item? if you are sure you have more than try to scroll on a ListView item

Comment: Are you getting any images ?

Comment: The no of images per each TextView is not same always just like in image where there are many images for 1 date and so on. And they may vary. Can you give an example. I couldn't get " try to scroll on a ListView item".

Comment: Yes I am getting images.But problem is the TextView appears for each row  along with the images.

Comment: can you show me the current view of the ListView ? a screenshot of the page?

Comment: @Arlind Added screenshot of what I am getting now.

Comment: okay on the ic_launcher trying scrolling left-right up-down, The gridview might not be fully shown

Comment: Dude did you get my question. I am asking about the Textview and you are mentioning about scrolling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85328/discussion-between-arlind-and-risingup).